# How to have an accuracy for comparing 2 lists in python?

Tags: python

I may not explain clearly.
I want to have a comparing function to identify whether the values of the same index from 2 lists are the same or not.

For example, 2 lists A and B, which should be the same(accuracy =100%).

```
A=[1,2,1,1,3,4,3,2,5]       
B=[4,2,4,4,3,1,3,2,5]
```

since A(0),A(2),A(3) are the same value = 1,and B(0),B(2),B(3) are the same value = 4; A(1),A(7) are the same value = 2, the same as B(1),B(7);
A(4),A(6) are the same value = 3, the same as B(4),B(6);
A(5), unique value in list A, is the same as B(5); 
A(8), unique value in list A, is the same as B(8).

And then taking the same rule for list C & D, which accuracy should be 80%.

```
C=[1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,6]
D=[3,4,4,4,1,5,5,6,5,6]
```

D(7) should be the same value as D(5),D(6), not the same with D(9), and D(8) should not be the same value as D(5),D(6), which should be a standalone value.

> notice: the value in list may not be sequential number.  list A can
>   also be [1,26,1,1,30,4,30,26,5], and B can be[4,22,4,4,3,100,3,22,5].
>   Which I still take them to be the same.

How can I have an accuracy of a comparing function to check it?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why `A` and `B` are supposed to have "accuracy" 100%. Would that not imply that the lists are equal? `A` and `B` are not equal, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Percentage Overlap of Two Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29929074/percentage-overlap-of-two-lists)

Comment: What about in the case of the sixth index (index = 5) in `A` and `B`? There's seemingly no pattern there, so could you expand a bit on your definition of "accuracy?"

Comment: @not_a_robot it looks like its pattern with 1st index

Comment: Interesting problem. So you want to find a mapping that maps the element from list B to those of list A with the greatest-possible overlap?

Comment: @not_a_robot : for the comparing rule of list A & B, the index of each value are all the same, so accuracy is 100%. But for list C & D, since D(7) and D(8) are incorrect in list D (2 incorrect in 10 elements), so the accuracy is 80%. And the value of the sixth index (index = 5) in A and B, are unique in each list.

Comment: I guess the tricky part is if you have lists `A = [1,1,1,1,1]` and `B = [2,3,3,3,3]`. You could iterate the lists in pairs, and set `2` equal to `1` at the first element, but then the accuracy is only 20%, whereas it's 80% if you ignore the first and set `3` equal to `1` later.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare the length of the set intersection to the length of the set union:

- How many elements are in both lists? (set intersection `&`)
- How many elements are there in total? (set union `|`)

This method doesn't take position or distribution into account:

```
A = [1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 5]
B = [4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3, 2, 5]

C = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6]
D = [3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6]

def overlapping_percentage(x, y):
    return (100.0 * len(set(x) & set(y))) / len(set(x) | set(y))

print(overlapping_percentage(A, B))
# 100.0
print(overlapping_percentage(C, D))
# 83.3
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! What if the D=[3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 5, 5, 2, 5, 6], the overlapping_percentage(C, D) will be 100%. I think the value of D(7)=2 is not the same as D(5) & D(6)=5.

Comment: @karenwu: Sorry, it appears I didn't get your question. My method only cares about unique elements, not about their distribution or place.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different method, which might be closer to what you want. It's not perfect and you'll probably have to optimize it.

To be honest, I don't understand exactly where those 80% come from.

This method extracts a "fingerprint" out of lists: where the elements are placed, independently from their values. The fingerprints are then compared to one another:

```
from collections import defaultdict

A=[1,2,1,1,3,4,3,2,5]
B=[4,2,4,4,3,1,3,2,5]

C = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6]
D = [3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6]

def fingerprint(lst):
    r = defaultdict(list)
    for i,x in enumerate(lst):
        r[x].append(i)
    return sorted(r.values())

fA = fingerprint(A)
# [[0, 2, 3], [1, 7], [4, 6], [5], [8]]
fB = fingerprint(B)
# [[0, 2, 3], [1, 7], [4, 6], [5], [8]]
fC = fingerprint(C)
# [[0], [1, 2, 3], [4], [5, 6, 7], [8], [9]]
fD = fingerprint(D)
# [[0], [1, 2, 3], [4], [5, 6, 8], [7, 9]]

print((100.0*sum(1 for a,b in zip(fA, fB) if a == b)/len(fB)))
# 100.0

print((100.0*sum(1 for c,d in zip(fC, fD) if c == d)/len(fD)))
# 60.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! i'll try it first.

Answer (score 0):

It too late to answer ,but I  did same thing in another way, and you can calculate each percentage of numbers same with another list in same index.

I'll just give you my code , you may refer to it.

```
def accuracy(self,*args):
        check = final_result['train_num'] == final_result['test_num']
        passed = final_result[check]
        accuracy = len(passed.index) / len(final_result.index)
        analysis = passed['test_num'].value_counts()
        analysis = analysis / 50  
        analysis['accuracy']=round(accuracy,5)
        pd.Series.to_csv(analysis,csvpath+"accuracy.csv",sep=',')
        print("accuracy：{:.3f}".format(accuracy))
```

`train_num` `test_num`is 2 columns of a dataframe `final_result`,you can replace it with your data.

**be careful** with `analysis = analysis / 50`,**50** is total degree of each elements in my data, you should change it.